# How to adjust Outlook Mailbox Reading Pane Preview

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I recently made a change that shows several icons for an email. This greatly reduces the amount I can read before clicking into the email. See below for example. You can see that it will show me all the icons for Important, Reminder, Attachment, etc.

[image: icons in email]

The email reading pane should not have columns showing if the email has something. See below example for how I would like for it to look.

[image: No icons]

Comment: That appears to be Outlook Web Mail.  Perhaps adjust your title.

Comment: Have you tried resetting your reader pane view settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Click on View. Change the Reading pane to either Right (or Bottom) as it is set currently to Off.

[image]

- Deselect `Show Focused Inbox`. This will allow to see `All` and `Unread` categories instead of `Focused` and `Others`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Click **View > Change View > Compact**, so that you can see both the icons and the reading pane.
[image]